# Preventing popup-blocker when using window.open from interval

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, popup-blocker

I am working on some js code that is called from a button click, starts some asynchronous action that may result in a window that needs to be opened.
To prevent popup-blockers I need to make sure the window.open call is done from the button-click.

I have been playing around with setTimeout and setInterval to check every 100ms or so if the async action is done and open the window if needed.

I simulate this in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgansevles/aao9yj4f/)
by calling a function via setInterval n times, the n-th call calls window.open.

Javascript:

```
// in chrome this only works with n = 1, otherwise the open-call is blocked
var n = 2
var timer

function tst1() {
    console.log('tst1.start ' + n)
    if (--n == 0) {
        clearInterval(timer)
        window.open('http://google.com/', '_blank')
    }
    console.log('tst1.done')
}

function tst() {
    timer = setInterval(tst1, 1000)
}
```

Html:

```
<button onclick="tst()">Click me</button>
```

Problem is, this only works first time (n=1 on first line in js code), when n is set to 2 or more, it works in Firefox but not in chrome.

Any idea how to make this work in all modern browsers?

Rob

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4989867/4332533

Comment: possible duplicate of [opening new windows after specifc interval of time using window.open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989537/opening-new-windows-after-specifc-interval-of-time-using-window-open)

Comment: I'm literally going to report this as a Firefox bug.

Comment: Not really sure what you're doing, but if you're going to open a new window you should do it as the immediate cause of a user action. Websites that just "randomly" (from the user's point of view) open windows are generally not websites that the user will return to later.

Comment: The new window is supposed to open from the button-onclick, so it is not at random.
Problem is that I have to wait for an asynchronous action to complete (a message is sent over a websocket and a response message may require a window.open).

I also wonder why it does work with n=1, the first call to tst1 is done when the button on-click has already returned so some state from the button-click-threat is kept.
But only for the first, why not for the second?