# New window in ajax call blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window

I've searched on the internet for a while for my solution, but none of the solutions worked for me or I didn't used it correct (I think).

I have a function which looks like this and is being called when a image is clicked:

```
function goToGoogle() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax("url/path", {
            data: "data"
        }, function(data){
            window.open("https://www.google.nl", "_blank");
        });
   }, 10000);
}
```

When `window.open` is called, a message pops up and says that the popup is blocked.

I've tried to create a variable with `window.open` in it (`var myWindow = window.open( ... );`) and then set the correct url with `myWindow.location = "www.correct.url";`. But this will result in a error in the console.log, which says that myWindow is undefined and location can't be called because of that.

Another thing I tried was to set `async` to false in the ajax call, but that's depreciated.

Does anyone how to make sure it opens a new window, even a few seconds after the click event?

By the way, I need the timeout of 10 seconds.. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that when the timeout is higher than 1sec (1000ms), chrome says no: https://jsfiddle.net/x30j8ftq/2/

Comment: Soo, what do you suggest to do? I need a timeout of 10 seconds.. @Pimmol

Comment: I'm not sure. I would consider for Martin's aswer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989537/opening-new-windows-after-specifc-interval-of-time-using-window-open

Comment: @pimmol It doesn't give me a clear solution. The user knows when a new window will open, so that's not a problem..

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly, because

> a message pops up and says that the popup is blocked.

That's just a browser policy to block popups. That's up to user to allow open popups on your site or to forbid.

Comment: My end-users probably won't know very much about comuter and/or websites. If the a message that a popup was blocked, they probably won't think about allowing popups on my site..